Bad to Badly, please help
What is it called when you change bad to badly? Bad is an adjective and badly is an adverb. What is the process of changing from an adjective to an adverb called? Is it conjugation?

FYI, conjugation is changing the form of a verb to match the subject, e.g. "I am" -> "you are" -> "he is".

The process is usually called “adverb formation”, and less commonly adverbalization.
